# Use polygon as search area overpass api / overpass turbo

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm fairly new at using overpass API, I finally managed to generate a query to retrieve all nodes within an area by using overpass-turbo wizard.

Using `highway=* in "Paulino Navarro"` in the wizard generates me the following query.

```
/*
This has been generated by the overpass-turbo wizard.
The original search was:
“highway=* in "Paulino Navarro"”
*/
[out:json][timeout:25];
// fetch area “Paulino Navarro” to search in
{{geocodeArea:Paulino Navarro}}->.searchArea;
// gather results
(
  // query part for: “highway=*”
  node["highway"](area.searchArea);
  way["highway"](area.searchArea);
  relation["highway"](area.searchArea);
);
// print results
out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

However, **how could I use a polygon as a search area?** maybe something like `highway=* in poly([lat,lon],[lat,lon],...,[lat,lon])` or how can I do that on the query itself.

I don't quite understand the documentation in overpass wiki nor overpass-turbo wizard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [polygon filter is explained in the Overpass QL documentation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#By_polygon_.28poly.29).

[Example](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/RIe):

```
[out:xml][timeout:30];
way[highway=primary](poly:"50.7 7.1 50.7 7.2 50.75 7.15");
(._;>;);
out;
```

Answer (score 3):

If the polygon you want to query inside of is an OSM feature, you can also query using an [area ID](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#By_area_.28area.29).
Area IDs are generated by the Overpass server to make querying data within existing polygons easier. You can determine the area ID for a way by adding `2400000000` to the way ID and the area ID for a relation by adding `3600000000` to the relation ID (assuming that the way or relation is a valid area feature).

Example:

```
[out:xml][timeout:30];
way[highway=primary](area:2400000001);
(._;>;);
out;
```